# Grails fail at test -app

Tags: grails, testing

I have my domain Class and my groovy class for unit test

```
class Product {

    String product_code
    String store
    int price
    String notes
    //static hasOne = [description: Description]

    static constraints = {
    product_code blank:false, size: 1..15
    price blank:false, scale: 2
    store blank:false, size: 1..40
    notes blank:true , size: 1..150
    }   
}


import org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node.ParamsAction;
import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*
import org.pricer.model.Product;

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */


@TestFor(Product)
class ProductTests {
void testSomething() {
    if (Product.hasErrors()){
        fail "not pass"
    }else 
        assert "Pass"
    }
}
```

when i try tu run test-app my ProductTest.testSomething i get

```
No signature of method: org.pricer.model.Product.hasErrors() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: hasErrors(), getErrors(),
setErrors(org.springframework.validation.Errors), clearErrors(), hashCode()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.pricer.model.Product.hasErrors() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: hasErrors(), getErrors(), setErrors(org.springframework.validation.Errors), clearErrors(), hashCode()
at
org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:97)
at org.pricer.ProductTests.testSomething(ProductTests.groovy:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasErrors()` is an instance method. When you call `Product.hasErrors()` you're calling a class/static method, which in this case, does not exist.

So, as majkelo said, you need a `Product` instance first. But, you also need to [trigger domain class validation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) so that if there are errors, `hasErrors()` will report them.

```
def product = new Product(product_code: 'ABC', store: 'StackOverflow', price: 1000000)

product.validate() /* You can also call product.save() to validate. */

if(product.hasErrors()) {
    /* Do your thing */
}
```

### A short-cut

You can combine validation and error checking like this:

```
if(product.validate()) {
    /* validation passed. */
} else {
   /* validation failed. */
}
```

Comment: @guillermo-nahuel-varelli, I *literally* just set up a Slack community for new Grails developers. Unlike the official Grails Slack community, which tends to cover advanced topics, this new one is for people new to Grails. You can get in here: http://emmanuelrosa.com/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't instantiate domain class Product in your test. Try f.e.:

```
void testSomething() {
    def product = new Product()
    if (product.hasErrors()){
        //do something
    }
}
```